# How to remove heading numbers in Jupyter during pdf conversion?

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

When I use the heading tags (# ##, etc) using markdown, they are always converted to numbered sections during pdf-latex conversion.

How to indicate unnumbered headings in markdown in Jupyter Notebook (IPython)?

I realize this can be done by adding a '*' right next to each section directly in the latex document, but is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 30):

You can write an unnumbered heading by appending `{-}` or `{.unnumbered}` to the Markdown cell, e.g.:

```
Heading {-}
```

The output is a heading without a number, like so:

## Heading

This is documented in [Pandoc's Markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) which is an extended and slightly revised version of the [original Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this @jsb. BTW, any background for us? I couldn't seem to find any mention of this in the docs.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some background and links to documentation.

Comment: It works, but it is annoying to see the "{-}" symbol in the notebook, since it does not understand it as a special instruction.

Answer (score 8):

You can clic the Table Of Contents icon.

A panel should open in the left side. Clic on the "configuration" icon [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfi9L.png)

De-select **Automatically number headings** [2]

See the screenshot

[image: See the screeshot]

Comment: For this you need have the toc-plugin

Comment: This does not work for me. It only removes numbering from the notebook, not the PDF.

Comment: Same here - doesn't work for PDF export, only in the notebook.

Comment: If you want them off by default, uncheck this setting in the toc extension's configuration found in the Nbextensions tab of the Jupyter Home Page screen (you may need to uncheck "disable configuration for nbextensions without explicit compatibility" to access its configuration).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the nb extensions active, you can see the contents on the left hand side.  Just before the contents (but after the title "Contents"), there is a small letter "n". If you press the n, it removes the numbering from the headers.