# How to Print Table of Contents and Paragraph Numbers

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda3, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

With nbextensions I get notebooks to have an index table and paragraph numbering. The problem is that when I print or export, in  both cases, the index  disappear. Is it possible to do it with nbextensions? Is there any way to get they don't dissapear? I will appreciate your help

This is a imágen of my notebook.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question has been answered here [How to remove heading numbers in Jupyter during pdf conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077571/how-to-remove-heading-numbers-in-jupyter-during-pdf-conversion). You can disable the table by clicking on the settings icon and deselecting the options you no longer need and then use `Heading {-}` to remove paragraph numbering when you print to PDF.

Comment: Excuse me. My English is not good and the question indicated the opposite of what the problem is. I have corrected the text of the question. Thank you

Comment: No worries. So, by "index table", do you mean the "Contents" table by the left of the screen? You want that to appear in your PDF export?